# integral on erfc function between x to infiity

Tags: integration, error-function

I need to calculate the next integral: $\int_{x}^{\infty }\operatorname{erfc}(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})d\xi $

**My attempt:**

$u=\frac{\xi }{2\sqrt{D\cdot t}}\rightarrow du=\frac{d\xi }{2\sqrt{D\cdot t}}$

$2\sqrt{D\cdot t}\int \operatorname{erf}(u)du\rightarrow 2\sqrt{D\cdot t}[u\cdot \operatorname{erfc}(u)-\frac{e^{-u^{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}]\rightarrow 2\sqrt{D\cdot t}[\frac{\xi }{2\sqrt{D\cdot t}}\cdot erfc(\frac{\xi }{2\sqrt{D\cdot t}})-\frac{e^{-\frac{\xi ^{2}}{4Dt}}}{\sqrt{\pi }}]|_{x}^{\infty }$

At $\infty$ we will get:$\frac{\infty }{2\sqrt{Dt}}\operatorname{erfc}(\infty )-\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\infty }{4Dt}}\sqrt{\pi }}\rightarrow \infty \cdot 0$

Where is my mistake?
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Indeterminate form $\infty \cdot 0$.  Your calculus text should have a discussion of that.  As $\xi \to +\infty$, we have $\operatorname{erfc}(\xi/2\sqrt{Dt})$ goes to zero much vaster than $1/\xi$.  Your general mistake is "substitute in $\infty$" when you should be taking a limit as $\xi \to \infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar Can you please explain once again? so, in this case, zero is stronger then infinity ? can you please say why? we did not cover this material in class so I am a little bit struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Find the integral $$\int_{x}^berfc(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})d\xi$$. This integral can be calculated  by writing $$\int_{x}^berfc(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})d\xi$$ $$=\int_{x}^b (\xi)' erfc(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})d\xi$$ and integrating by parts.  $$\int_{x}^b (\xi)' erfc(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})d\xi$$ $$=(\xi erfc(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}}))|_x^b -\int_{x}^b \xi erfc'(\frac{\xi }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})d\xi$$
(ii) Take the expression you found for the integral in (i) and take the limit as $b \to \infty$. Note that the integral on the right above is easy because $erfc'$ is just $constant \text { } e^{- \xi^2/constant}$ and thus can be found immediately upon substituting $\zeta = \xi^2$ The limit $$\lim_{b \to \infty}b \text { } erfc(\frac{b }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})$$ $$=\lim_{b \to \infty}\frac {erfc(\frac{b }{2 \sqrt{D\cdot t}})}{\frac{1}{b}}$$ and this limit can be found by l"Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Sorry for answering only now, thank you for the explanation it helped me a lot:)